# Pyspark Convert PipelinedRDD to Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 2.3.1 and I'm performing NLP in spark when I print the type of RDD it shows **<class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'>** and when executing

> `rdd.collect()`

command on PipelineRDD it's output is

> ['embodiment present invention include pairing two wireless device placing least one two device pairing mode performing least one pairing motion event least one wireless device satisfy least one pairing condition detecting satisfaction least one pairing condition pairing two wireless device response detecting satisfaction least one pairing condition numerous aspect provided', 'present invention relates wireless communication system specifically present invention relates method transmitting control information pucch wireless communication system apparatus comprising step of obtaining plurality second modulation symbol stream corresponding plurality scfdma single carrier frequency division multiplexing symbol diffusing plurality first modulation symbol stream form first modulation symbol stream corresponding scfdma symbol within first slot obtaining plurality complex symbol stream performing dft discrete fourier transform precoding process plurality second modulation symbol stream transmitting plurality complex symbol stream pucch wherein plurality second modulation symbol stream scrambled scfdma symbol level dog church aardwolf abacus']

I want to create a data frame like this to add every word into rows of the data frame.

```
+--------------+
|    text      |
+--------------+
|  embodiment  |
|  present     |
|  invention   |
....
....
|  aardwolf    |
|  abacus      |
+--------------+
```

Here is my code

```
import pyspark
import nltk
import string


from pyspark import SparkContext
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

from pyspark.ml.feature import NGram
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType,StructType,StructField,StringType

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Spark Example').getOrCreate()

Source_path="Folder_of_multiple_text_file"


data=sc.textFile(Source_path)

lower_casetext = data.map(lambda x:x.lower())



# splitting_rdd = lower_casetext.map(lambda x:x.split(" "))
# print(splitting_rdd.collect())


# Function to perform Sentence tokeniaztion
def sent_TokenizeFunct(x):
    return nltk.sent_tokenize(x)

sentencetokenization_rdd = lower_casetext.map(sent_TokenizeFunct)

# Function to perform Word tokenization

def word_TokenizeFunct(x):
    splitted = [word for line in x for word in line.split()]
    return splitted

wordtokenization_rdd = sentencetokenization_rdd.map(word_TokenizeFunct)


# Remove Stop Words

def removeStopWordsFunct(x):
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    stop_words=set(stopwords.words('english'))
    filteredSentence = [w for w in x if not w in stop_words]
    return filteredSentence
stopwordRDD = wordtokenization_rdd.map(removeStopWordsFunct)


# Remove Punctuation marks

def removePunctuationsFunct(x):
    list_punct=list(string.punctuation)
    filtered = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in list_punct) for s in x] 
    filtered_space = [s for s in filtered if s] #remove empty space 
    return filtered
rmvPunctRDD = stopwordRDD.map(removePunctuationsFunct)

# Perform Lemmatization

def lemma(x):

    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

    final_rdd = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(s) for s in x]
    return final_rdd

lem_wordsRDD = rmvPunctRDD.map(lemma)

# Join tokens

def joinTokensFunct(x):
    joinedTokens_list = []
    x = " ".join(x)
    return x

joinedTokensRDD = lem_wordsRDD.map(joinTokensFunct)


print(joinedTokensRDD.collect())
print(type(joinedTokensRDD))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my code by removing join Tokens Step and directly convert **lem_wordsRDD** into the data frame by the following code.

```
df = lem_wordsRDD.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF(["features"])

explod_df = df.withColumn("values", explode("features"))

tokenized_df = explod_df.select("values")
tokenized_df.show()
```